# Get Sales Data of Current Day

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, reports, grand-total

I can get sales revenue with this

```
$orderTotals = Mage::getModel( 'sales/order' )->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter( 'created_at', array( 'from' => date( 'Y-m-d' ), 'to' => date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( '+1 days' ) ) ) )
    ->addAttributeToSelect( 'grand_total' )
    ->getColumnValues( 'grand_total' );
$totalSum = array_sum( $orderTotals );
$totalSum = Mage::helper( 'core' )->currency( $totalSum, true, false );

echo $totalSum;
```

But how do I get the total amount of orders and sales shipping total?

also is there a better way to find current days orders as I think I've done it a confusing way. Will this only show today? It appears to look right.

*Update*

Just a thought, is there a way to count the orders?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the best solution to do the calculation directly in the Database.

```
/* Load the Collection by Date */
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => date('Y-m-d'), 'to' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 days'))));

$order->getSelect()
    ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS) //remove existings selects
    ->columns(array('grand_total' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(grand_total)'))) //add expresion to sum the grand_total
    ->columns(array('count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(entity_id)'))) //add expression to count the orders
    ->columns(array('shipping_total' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(shipping_amount+shipping_tax_amount)'))); //add expression to calculate the shipping costs

$data = $order->getFirstItem(); //because this is a collection, we need just the first item.

echo $data['grand_total'];
echo $data['count'];
echo $data['shipping_total'];
```